# android loop through database with cursor speed

Tags: android, sqlite, while-loop, cursor

I have read several posts here on speed issues when looping through a cursor and tried the answers given in these posts such as e.g. do not use getcolumnindex in the loop call this once etc.

However with a database having around 2400 records it takes around 3 to 5 minutes to finish.

The loop is running in an async task method so that it does not hang up the device and the database is handled via a database adapter.

The loop code is as follows :

```
    while (!exportrec.isAfterLast()) {
                    if ( exportrec.moveToNext() ) {
                    fulldate =  exportnumberformatter(exportrec.getInt(daye))
                            +"/"+exportnumberformatter(exportrec.getInt(monthe))+"/"
                            +String.valueOf(exportrec.getInt(yeare));

                    fulltime =  exportnumberformatter(exportrec.getInt(houre))+":"
                            +exportnumberformatter(exportrec.getInt(mine))+":"
                            +exportnumberformatter(exportrec.getInt(sece));

                    noiseid = exportrec.getInt(typee);
                    exportedinfo += exporttypes[id] +","+exportrec.getString(notee)+","+
                            fulldate+","+fulltime+" \n" ;  
                    } 
 }
```

The exportnumberformatter does the following :

```
 public String exportnumberformatter(int i) {
            String result = Integer.toString(i);

            if (result.length() >1 ) {

             return Integer.toString(i);
             }

           String zeroprefix = "";
           zeroprefix = "0"+result;


              return zeroprefix ;
        }
```

The cursor is called as follows before the loop to get the data  :

```
exportrec = MD.GetAllLogs(2, "date_sort");
exportrec.moveToFirst();
```

The MD is the database adapter and the GetAllLogs Method (this has been played with to try and speed things up and so the date_sort that is used is really ignored here):

```
public Cursor GetAllLogs(Integer i,String sortfield)
        {
            String sorted = "";
            if (i == 1 ) {
                sorted = "DESC";
            } else if (i == 2) {
                sorted = "ASC";
            } 


            return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_TYPE,COL_IMAGE, COL_INFO,COL_IMAGE,COL_HOUR,COL_SEC,COL_MIN,COL_DAY,COL_MON,COL_YEAR,COL_SORT_DATE},
                            null, null, null, null, COL_ID+" "+sorted);
        }
```

When I created the table in the database it had no indexes so I created these via the upgrade method. However they did not error or appear to fail when I did this but what I do not know is A) does the database/table need rebuilding after an index is created and B) how to tell if they have been created ? the two indexes were based on the ID as the first and a field that holds the year month day hour minute second all in on Long Integer.

I am concerned that the loop appears to be taking this long to read through that many records.

**Update:**

rtsai2000's and the suggestion from CL answer has improved the speed from minutes to seconds

Comment: Is `exportedinfo` a `String`? You should use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Is the index on the `COL_ID` column?

Comment: @CL would that make a lot of difference ? Yes it is just a string.  The column COL_ID is indexed as well yes

Comment: Why would Java have `StringBuilder` if it didn't make any difference? (And you are stepping over the first record.)

Comment: @CL was not meant to offend just wondered what the difference was that is all. BTW not stepping over first record, that info is stored before the loop starts. Didn't include it because it was not part of the loop. I will try the stringbuilder as you suggested . Thanks for your help CL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exportedInfo String is growing and growing. Save the results in an array and Stringify later (such as with StringBuilder).

You are not closing your cursor after reading the records.

```
List<String> exportedInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor exportrec = GetAllLogs();
try {
  while (exportrec.moveToNext()) {
    String info = String.format("%s, %s, %02d/%02d/%02d, %02d:%02d:%02d",
      exporttypes[id],
      exportrec.getString(notee),
      exportrec.getInt(daye),
      exportrec.getInt(monthe),
      exportrec.getInt(yeare),
      exportrec.getInt(houre),
      exportrec.getInt(mine),
      exportrec.getInt(sece));  
    exportedInfo.add(info);
  }
} finally {
  exportrec.close();
}
return exportedInfo;
```

Comment: thanks for the example. I do close the cursor just not included in my code snippets that is all. very helpful example BTW, will the loop stop when it reaches the end of the records? I thought not having another condition to check when it reaches the end would be a problem

Comment: Also the year format is four digits so is the formatting %04d for this ?

Comment: Tested this method and it is defiantly much faster thanks! however I have now got to feed the string array into a text file. tried doing another separate loop into a string to put that to my method that writes the file but as before this slowed the app down so I have go to work out how to sort that out now. Thanks again rtsai2000